# SAME70 read external interrupt polarity in ISR

Tags: c, microchip, isr, asf

I'm currently working on a SAME70 board made by Atmel. I plugged on it an extention OLED1 board  (Atmel too) on EXT1 port. My goal is to recover the information about interrupt type (falling or raising) when I'm pressing the button 3 on OLED1 board. I have a function which allows me to set the different registers related to an interrupts. But unfortunately the register which indicates the polarity (FLHSR) stay always at 0 whatever the state of the button.
Below my code.

```c
#include <asf.h>

void set_Interupt_Pin()
{
    uint32_t mask = 1 << 19;  /*bitmasking*/
    PIOA->PIO_IER = mask;    /*enable interruptions*/
    PIOA->PIO_AIMER = mask;  /*add new interruption*/
    PIOA->PIO_ESR = mask;     /*set interrupt source on edge*/
    PIOA->PIO_REHLSR = mask; /* set interrupt to rising edge*/
    PIOA->PIO_FELLSR= mask; /* set interrupt to falling edge*/
    NVIC_DisableIRQ(ID_PIOA);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(ID_PIOA);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ID_PIOA);   /*set NVIC to get interruptions from PIOA*/
    NVIC_SetPriority(ID_PIOA, 4); /*priority 4*/
    
}

void PIOA_Handler(void)
{
    printf("FRLHSR: %x\n",PIOA->PIO_FRLHSR); /*state of polarity event */
    printf("ISR: %x\n",PIOA->PIO_ISR); 
    printf("ELSR: %x\n",PIOA->PIO_ELSR); 
    printf("AIMMR: %x\n",PIOA->PIO_AIMMR); 
}

int main(void)
{
    const usart_serial_options_t usart_serial_options = {
        .baudrate     = CONF_UART_BAUDRATE,
        .charlength   = CONF_UART_CHAR_LENGTH,
        .paritytype   = CONF_UART_PARITY,
        .stopbits     = CONF_UART_STOP_BITS
    };
    sysclk_init();
    board_init();
    stdio_serial_init(CONF_UART, &usart_serial_options);
    set_Interupt_Pin();
    while(1){}
}
```

You can see here the result of print when I press button (first part) and I release button (second part).

[image: terminal when I press button]
Best regards

Comment: Read about the debouncing

Comment: I am wildly guessing here, without intending to offend. If you try to find out the polarity of an occurred interrupt I feel that you got it backward. I expect to configure ports in a way like "I want the interrupt triggered when there is an edge on the input voltage. In this case I want the trigger when there is a rising/falling edge." I.e. you configure what you need. If you e.g. configure for falling edge and an interrupt occurred, then you know that it was falling. Your desription I read (and maybe it is my mistake) like you expect an ISR on any edge and then try to find out.

Comment: "any edge" is a possible configuration on many ports I have worked with, but then the information is not available, you only get to know that there is "any edge". If you always read 0, then it might not be runtime info on the edge which occurred and instead be what you configured (or default) maybe 0 means falling. If you write (not read) a 1 there then the rising edge triggers. Or of course vice versa. If I am close let me know. If we get this sorted out I turn this into an answer. Otherwise (if I am off) I delete my distracting comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your absolutly right about what i'm intending to do. I indeed tried to setup the interupt on any edge using the ESR register and my board datasheet is explicitly stipulating that one canno't read the polarity in this mode and that's why I'm instead trying to put both register REHLSR and FELLSR to one. If I understerdand correctly what you're suggesting, FRLHSR is maybe not a runtime register and I can't proceed that way. Do you know if there a way to firstly make sure of that, and if that's so, to retrieve the polarity by any other mean ?

Comment: I am guessing, not having the manual. Try to find out whether you can setup TWO interrupt routines, one for rising edge one for falling. Then in each rountine you always know what happened. But be aware that this does not mean that after a rising edge during the corresponding ISR the port is high. I expect that 10 quick alternatiing edges (bouncing, as 0 already mentioned) might only trigger much fewer ISRs of both kinds - and not even pairwise. Please allow me to mention https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I.e. please take a step back and consider your goal.

Comment: I did start by checking out if I was able to set two interrupts on the same pin but the interrupt vector table/NVIC of my ARM cpu doesn't offer the ability to do so, as far as I understand. I may be wrong, but anyway the question I'm asking here is, I believe, not a XY problem as I'm trying to understand the limitations and functionnalities of this board more than achieving a goal. If someone can assure me that one canno't read the polarity in the ISR, I'll take that as an answer.